# Selenium Java wait unitl text appears

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a text box where I enter the text during tests, for example "cars", but very often not whole text appear in the text box, for example only "car". So my question is how can I wait until whole text will appear and how can I check that?

This

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "text"));`
```

Doesn't work for me. It is the same result as without it.

[EDIT]

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Doesn't work for me too.

Also

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(...).getAttribute("value").length() != 0;
    }
});
```

Will not work for me, because there is no value, because it is not saved.

Comment: You could try `wait.until(x => element.text() == "text")`, not entirely sure if that will solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, the only thing missing is a loop to catch Selenium TimeOut Exceptions whilst you are polling the element. Also, I would rather go with the isDisplayed() instead of isTextPresent() and focus my Xpath on locating the 'cars' text that you are after.

Here is the method for waiting, it will return true/or false based on if the element was present during the polling time (10sec for example); worth noting that if the element is found as present earlier than the 10sec limit the loop will break and will return true:

```
 public boolean waitForElement(String elementXpath, int timeOut) {

    try{                    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut); 
    boolean elementPresent=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementXpath)).isDisplayed());

    System.out.printf("%nElement is present [T/F]..? ")+elementPresent;
    }        
    catch(TimeoutException e1){e1.printStackTrace();elementPresent=false;}          

    return elementPresent;   
 }
```

Now, it really boils down how you 'grab' the element. You mentioned, you want the full cars text to appear. Hypothetically speaking let's say the element is located by id=brand and you want the text inside an a href link. So you want something like this for your xpath:

> //div[@id='brand']//a[text()[contains(., 'cars')]]

*Please note that the above is **case-sensitive** so it will fail if you are looking for **Cars.***

Best of luck!

*Update after OP's comment:*

Correcting the way we identify the web-element:

> //div[@id='widget_dijit_form_TextBox_0']//div//input

Now all is needed is to use the waitForElement above until the  element appears. When it does you can grab the text by using:

```
String textInsideInputTag = elementPresent.getText();
```

Now you can compare this to your intended value (i.e. 'cars'):

```
if(textInsideInputTag.equals("cars")){
System.out.println("Successfully found cars inside <input> tag");
}
else{
System.out.println("Couldn't locate cars in the element!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but `//div[@id='widget_dijit_form_TextBox_0']//div//input[text()[contains(., 'cars')]]` doesn't work for me, only //div[@id='widget_dijit_form_TextBox_0']//div//input. It is because I only type text into this input and it is not saved anywhere I think.

Comment: Hi Robmax, then it is my fault; I understood your question wrong! I didn't realise you were typing in an <input> tag, it makes sense the text no to appear then. An alternative way will be to loop using the driver wait above but look for the <input> tag and get text. I'll update my answer..